# make android tv remote button like netflix button

Tags: android, android-tv

I'm developing an android tv app and wonder how to start my app directly from button on remote like netflix button on some remote.

**I currently have two methods.**

1. Start a service listening for specific keys when boot.
2. In AndroidManifest make activity filter voice_command and use it.

Is there any other better way?

Comment: You may refer with this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/navigation) which explains the minimum requirements for creating effective TV app navigation scheme and how to apply those requirements to your app. For more recommendations on designing effective selection and focus for your TV app, see [Patterns for TV](https://developer.android.com/design/tv/patterns.html).

Comment: Or maybe I should ask directly: How did netflix button on remote work?

Comment: I finally use AccessibilityService to get my purpose, tks.